# How to get a specific column of a table in a dataset?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am learning Powershell script to automate some SQL tasks.  I used DataAdapter to fill the Dataset and I got a correct number from the console saying 14 columns are selected.  However, I am stuck at using a loop to print out a specific column of a table from a dataset.

Update:

1) TheMadTechnician fixed my problem - A SQL query mistake.
2) I have updated the corrected code here.  Also, I added Method3 to help others to print a better formatted table.

My Code:

```
# $ConnectionString is the server and my account info.
$SqlQuery = $("SELECT * FROM MyTable")

$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection($ConnectionString)
$SqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand($SqlQuery, $Connection)
$Connection.Open()

$DataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$DataAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCommand
$Dataset = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
$DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset)

$Connection.Close()

# Method1:
foreach ($Row in $Dataset.Tables[0].Rows) {       
    Write-Host "col_1:$($Row.Id)   col_2:$($Row.CreatedDateTime)    col_3:$($Row.DeactivatedDateTime)"
}

# Method2:
foreach ($Row in $Dataset.Tables[0].Rows) {  
    Write-Host "col_1:$($Row[0])   col_2:$($Row[1])   col_3:$($Row[2])"
}

# Method3:
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Dataset.Tables.Count; $i++) {
     $Dataset.Tables[$i] | format-table  | out-host
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of how you fill the DA?  I assume you fill the DA once and run the three methods on the same $Dataset

Comment: if you are just trying to print data why not use  `invoke-sqlcmd` PowerShell cmdlet and get a PowerShell object returned. It is much easier to work with. For example `$data = invoke-sqlcmd -serverinstance 'server\instance' -database 'db' -query 'my select or exec statement';

$data | select-object -property columnname, columnname2
## other data acess method could be
$data.ColumnName`

You could also put the `$data`  object in a loop and access the columns the same way record by record. If you are interested in this as a solution I will post an answer with a full example.

Comment: @JoeC , Code is posted.

Comment: @jkdba , Thanks for your suggestion.  If I need your approach, I will open another thread to ask you.  :)

Comment: @jkdba , I opened a new thread to ask you how to use invoke-sqlcmd to print a column of a table.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099378/how-to-use-invoke-sqlcmd-to-access-a-specific-column-of-a-table-in-a-dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to `SELECT * FROM MyTable` and it should work. Right now it is only showing CreatedDateTime because that is the only thing your query is returning.