# How to use invoke-sqlcmd to access a specific column of a table in a dataset?

Tags: powershell

As discussed from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097975/how-to-get-a-specific-column-of-a-table-in-a-dataset), User jkdba suggested a different method to access a column of a table.  Since the original thread was fixing a side problem, I opened this thread to find out how to use invoke-sqlcmd to access a specific column of a table.  If anyone has a different approach, please don't hestitate to share.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can use the same methods of accessing column values when using your Data Adapter method. I prefer to use the PowerShell equivalent (`Invoke-SQLCmd`) to `SqlCommand` and `DataAdapter` as it is a lot less code, it's readable, and it is friendly to any non-devs that might be looking at it. As a side note Invoke-SQLCmd is mostly make the same underlying Dot Net calls.

So before I get into `Invoke-SQLCmd` and basic object property accessing you can use the same property accessing techniques with your `$DataSet` object from your other post just like this:

- This will return the table or data table object `$DataSet.Tables`.
- This will return all of the column values of the data table object `$DataSet.Tables.ColumnName`.

When you use `Invoke-SQLCmd`, it will return a PowerShell array object full of Dot Net DataRows. It is basically the same just less code.

**Running the Invoke-Sqlcmd**:

```
 ## Run Query and Get Date
 $SQLResults = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'Server\Instance' -Database 'DatabaseName' -Query 'select * from mytable'
 ## You can always see all of the properties and methods associated with the result object by running the command below
 $SQLResults | Get-Member
 ## The above will show the PowerShell understood properties and implicit stuff it does.
 ## Adding -Force to the Get-Member call will show the true datatypes and properties.
```

**Get all values for a column**:

```
 ## If you just want to list all of the values for a column you would do variable.property name aka results.columnname
 $SQLResults.MyColumnName
 ## If The column name has a space in it, you can do this
 $SQLResults.'My Column Name'
 ## Both of the above results will dump all of the values from the query results for the column of 'MyColumnName'
```

**Access each column of a row**:

```
 foreach($Row in $SQLResults)
 {
     ## this would print the value of each column for reach row one by one.
     $Row.ColumnName
     $Row.ColumnName1
     $Row.ColumnName2
 }
```

**Adding a Column to the Results**:

You can easily add a column to the results after performing some row by row processing by using the `Add-Member` function.

```
 foreach($Row in $SQLResults)
 {
     ## some sort of row by row processing
     if($Row.ColumnName -ilike 'some*value')
     {
         $Row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'MYNewColumnName' -Value 'IfTrueLogicValue'
     }
     else
     {
         $Row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'MYNewColumnName' -Value 'IfFalseLogicValue'
     }

     ##Be Sure to output the row
     $Row
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your example.  Just a small question from this newbie...I got <System.Data.DataRow.Id>  from <Write-Host "$Row.Id">  in the foreach loop?  (Please ignore '< >' in this comment.)  When do I need to put a variable in quotes?  Thank you!

Comment: Remove quotes then the property `Id` can be evaluated to its value. Wrapping a `$var.property` in double quotes, PS is unable to evaluate the property's value. If you wanted to `Write-Host` a variable without accessing a property you would not need the quotes. If you wanted to concatenate `$Row.Id` with a string you have a few options. You can do something like this: `Write-Output "My RowID: $($Row.Id)"` in this case the `$()` will eval the `$Row.Id` property value then since it is in the `".."` it will concate with the "My RowID:".

Comment: You can also use string format (interpolation) to concatenate your string like so: `$string = 'My RowID: {0}' -f $Row.Id; Write-Output $String;`. As far as when to use the different quotes I recommend a simple google search there are plenty of great [articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+when+to+use+quotes+with+variables&oq=powershell+when+to+use+quotes+with+variables).